# Docker container not using latest composer.json file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, composer-php

I'm going crazy here.

I've been working on a `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` file for my project. I recently updated my project's dependencies. When I build the project outside of a container using `composer install`, it builds with the correct dependencies. However, when I build the project inside a docker container, it downloads and installs the latest dependencies, but then somehow runs the application using obsolete dependencies!

First of all, this is what my `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM composer

# Set the working directory within the docker container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy in the app, then install dependencies.
COPY . /app
RUN composer install
```

I have excluded the `composer.lock` file and the `vendor` directory in my `.dockerignore`:

```
vendor
composer.lock
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - app:/app
  webserver:
    image: richarvey/nginx-php-fpm
    volumes:
      - app:/var/www/html

volumes:
  app:
```

Note that the build process occurs within the `app` volume. I don't think this should be part of the problem, as I run `docker system prune` each time, to purge all existing volumes.

This is what I do to run the container. While troubleshooting, I have been running these commands to eliminate any cached files before starting the container:

```
$ docker system prune
$ docker-compose build --no-cache
$ docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

As I watch the dependencies install and download, *I can see that it is downloading and installing the right versions!* So it must have the correct `composer.json` file at some point in the process.

Yet somehow, once the build is complete and the application starts, I get the same old warnings about obsolete dependencies, and sure enough, and the `composer.json` inside the container is obsolete!

So my questions are:

1. How TF is the `composer.json` file in the container obsolete?
   *WHERE* is it getting the obsolete file from, since it no longer exists in any image or cache??
2. How TF is it managing to install the latest dependencies with this obsolete composer.json file, but then not using them, and in fact *reverting* the composer.json file and the dependencies??

Comment: Is the composer.json file the correct file when you `docker exec -ti [container] /bin/bash` and `cat` it?

Comment: No, it's not. It's obsolete. Yet `RUN composer install` *is* somehow using the latest the correct `composer.json`, because it I can see that it is installing the latest package versions during the installation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you copy your local files into the app-container and run `composer install` on this copy. Since this will not affect your host system, your webserver, which will actually serve your project will still use the outdated local version, instead of the copy from your other image.

You could try using [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) or something like this:

```
COPY FROM app:latest /app /var/www/html
```

This will copy the artifact from your "build-container", i.e. your project with the installed dependency in app, into the actual container that is running the code, i.e. webserver. Unfortunately, I don't think this will work (well) with your setup, where you mount the volume into that location.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm about to apply it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally fixed this issue, although parts of my original problem still confuse me.

Here's what I learned:

The `docker-compose up` process goes in this order:

1. If an image already exists, use it, even if the Dockerfile (or files used by it) has changed. (This can be avoided with `docker-compose up --build`).
2. If there is no existing image, build the image from the Dockerfile.
3. Mount the volumes specified in the docker-compose file.

A huge part of my problem was that I thought that the volumes were mounted *before* the build process, and that my application would be installed into this volume as a result of these commands:

```
COPY . /app
RUN composer install
```

However, these files were later overwritten when the volume was mounted at the same location within the container (`/app`).

Now, since I was not mounting a host directory, just an ephemeral, named volume, the `/app` directory should have been empty. I still don't understand why it wasn't, considering I was clearing my existing Docker volumes with `docker system prune` before each build. Whatever.

In the end, I used @dbrumann's solution. This was simpler, did not require the use of any Docker volumes, and avoids having a live `composer` container after the build process has completed (this would be bad for production). My `Dockerfile` now looks like this:

`Dockerfile`:

```
# Install dependencies using the composer image
FROM composer AS composer

# Set the working directory within the docker container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy in the app, then install dependencies.
COPY . .
RUN composer install

# Start the nginx server
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm

# Copy over files from the composer image, which is then discarded automatically
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY --from=composer /app .
```

And the new `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  webserver:
    build: .
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```